# How to change material onclick using .obj and .mtl files in Aframe

Tags: aframe

i'm able to load .obj and .mtl files in aframe, However i wanted to change those materials of the object onclick by pulling out the material names from .mtl file, but how do i do it in aframe ?

```
 <a-entity id="model" position="0 0 -2">
                 <a-entity obj-model = "obj: #tree-obj; mtl: #tree-mtl"  position="0 0 0" rotation="0 0 0" scale="0.8 0.8 0.8"></a-entity>  
          </a-entity>
```

i could replicate the same in threejs as follows

```
object.traverse( function( child ) { if ( child instanceof THREE.Mesh ) {
                            if (child.material.name == "xyz")  { //xyz from .mtl file
                                        child.material = Black;// black is a meshphong material                                                                                                       
                                        child.castShadow = true;
                                        child.receiveShadow = true;
                                    }
                        }
```

Comment: Have you tried having a different mtl file and replace it on click? `entityEl.addEventListener('click', function (evt) { evt.detail.el.setAttribute('obj-model', 'mtl', '#black"); );`

Comment: Since you have THREE.js code that does what you want, you can traverse and do the same thing in A-Frame – that same mesh will be a child of `el.object3D`, via `el.object3D.traverse()`.

Comment: @DiegoMarcos  i tried using this, but no luck 
 var map1 = document.querySelector('#model');
    
    document.querySelector('#image').addEventListener('click', function(evt) {
      
    evt.map1.setAttribute('obj:#true-obj;mtl:#tree-mtl1');

Comment: @DonMcCurdy i tried but couldn't catch up, can you please leave an example ?

Comment: @andyram kevin's answer below looks right to me. :)

Answer (score 1):

You can write a component that listens to a click event and does the same three.js code:

```
AFRAME.registerComponent('change-material-on-click', {
  schema: {
    target: {type: 'selector'}
  },

  init: function () {
    var el = this.el;  // Element to add click listener.
    var targetEl = this.data.target;  // Target to change material.

    el.addEventListener('click', function () {
      var mesh = targetEl.getObject3D('mesh');
      mesh.traverse(...);  // Do your logic here.
    });
  }
});
```

Then attach the component:

```
<a-image change-material-on-click="target: #model"></a-image>
<a-obj-model id="model" ...></a-obj-model>
```

Comment: Hi Kevin, sorry for the late reply, i tried the above code but i failed to get the required result . Can you please have a look at the small code here ? Kindly help me out, i'm new to this platform.

https://jsfiddle.net/rbyhb7fp/